# Getting strings.xml item value without R.string

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app and I wanted to get the value of an item in strings.xml but without using the `R.string method`.

Is this possible?

**Edit:**
I'll explain what the app does.
Basically, there's a word, let's call it "Rose", Rose can mean "Flower" or "First name", since it has two meanings, when the users chooses one of the two meanings, the app displays an explanation for the selected meaning.

I can't use `R.string.stringName` because I made a db that stores the relation between the name and the meaning and the correct explanation.

I'm sorry if it's not clear enough, I really don't know how to explain it.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use R.string or @string/

Comment: Please add some detail concerning why you don't want to use R.string please.

Comment: I'll edit the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason why you would do that is if you are developing a library and don't have direct access to **R** class of the end app. In that case you should use something like this

```
private String getSomeString() {
    try {
        return getContext().getResources().getString(getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("some_string_identifier", "string", getContext().getPackageName()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Not found, use a default
        return "1234567";
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't using the getIdentifier method extremely memory intensive?

Comment: Extremely? No. It's less performant than using R.string directly, but inside a library, you have no other choice if you want to access the strings from the end app that will be using your library.

Comment: Actually memory wise I don't think it makes any noticable difference, but it's slower in execution time.

Comment: I see, my fear is that it wouldn't really perform well, but if i have not other choice, i'll use the getIdentifier method, thanks.

Comment: I have seen your edit. When user clicks... he will not see the difference between these two methods. We are talking about microseconds here, at worst miliseconds. A human can't see the difference anyway

Comment: And it's also exception handled.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you can just simply use :

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
      String packageName = getPackageName();
      int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
      return getString(resId);
    }
```

To get string by it's name, and not `R.string`

Comment: You should ask your question clearly then, it's not straight R.string, what you want to do?

Comment: your resId = R.string.aString... anyway the question is weird, I know